# Linux Traceroute and Linux Tracert

Tags: linux, traceroute

I'm having a problem with `traceroute` on Linux. The command isn't working but `tracert` does work fine. Both commands are actually running the `traceroute` command as `tracert` is just a symbolic link to `traceroute`.

Why is it not working as expected?

Here's a screenshot showing the behavior:

[image: traceroute not working, just tracert]

Comment: There may be *other* programs in your shell's search path with one or both names. Try `./tracert`, `./traceroute` (to invoke the executables in your current location) and `which tracert` and `which traceroute` to see what is actually run when you don't specify the location.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program is looking at `argv[0]` (its name) and invoking different behavior based on which command (`tracert` or `traceroute`) you're using.

If you execute the program `tracert` then `argv[0]` is `tracert`.

So two commands, same executable, different paths through the code invoking different behavior.

On Ubuntu Linux:

```
   traceroute6 is equivalent to traceroute -6
   tracert is equivalent to traceroute -I
   tcptraceroute is equivalent to traceroute -T
```

Comment: Certainly a possibility, though it would be interesting to know *which* options are being flipped to explain the particular difference in behaviour.

Comment: Good idea to add that info -- done!

Comment: Fixed, same as traceroute -I.

Answer (score 1):

Add traceroute to your system PATH:

```
$echo $PATH
xxxxxxxx

$ which traceroute
/bin/traceroute
```

does xxxxxxxx contains traceroute? Then just make a soft link.